# How to remove certain HTML tags that are enclosed by other certain tags

Tags: php, html, regex

How can I remove specific HTML tags from a string, but only when they are within some other certain HTML tags?

Let's say I want to remove all `<br />` tags that are between `<strong>` and `</strong>`, but leave all other tags inside and all other `<br />` tags outside of `<strong></strong>` untouched.

Example string:

```
$t = "Optional start 1 <strong>bold stuff 1<br /></strong> optional end 1 and optional start 2 <strong>bold stuff 2<br /></strong>optional end 2 and break follows now <br />and text continues here in a new line, new strong comes here: <strong>here I am, very bold <br /> and I am still bold after a break.</strong>";
```

Approach:

```
$x = preg_replace("@(.*)(\<strong\>)(.*)\<br \/\>(.*)(\<\/strong\>)(.*)@U", "$1$2$3$4$5$6", $t);
```

Result:

```
$x = "Optional start 1 <strong>bold stuff 1</strong> optional end 1 and optional start 2 <strong>bold stuff 2</strong>optional end 2 and break follows now <br />and text continues here in a new line, new strong comes here: <strong>here I am, very bold and I am still bold after a break.</strong>";
```

My approach seems actually to work, but I am absolutely not sure, if it really does in more complex situations. Or if it will still work if there are certain markup errors within the string. Or maybe there is a better solution at all.

**EDIT:**

Since it's not the best idea to use RegEx for parsing HTML, according to comments and some other posts I've came across now, I tried this:

```
$DomDoc = new DOMDOcument;
$DomDoc->loadxml($t);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($DomDoc);
foreach($xpath->query('strong/br') as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
$x = $DomDoc->savexml();
```

It seems to work fine so far.

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Get a proper DOM API instead.

Comment: It's a pity you need to use regular expressions because it's a trivial XPATH query: `'//strong//br'`.

Comment: Also trivial with selector syntax `strong br`